# Grep for lines starting with strings from a pattern file

Tags: command-line, grep

I have a file (pattern file) I would like to feed into grep via `-f`, and I would like to find matches in another file (search file) where a string *starts with* that given pattern. For example:

**PATTERN_FILE**

```
1234
qwerty
chicken
```

**SEARCH_FILE**

```
12345
543212345
qwerty
1fwf32sgww
chicken fingers
```

Given the above files, grep should return the following lines

```
12345
qwerty
chicken fingers
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could prepend `^` to all lines in `PATERN_FILE` to pass to `grep -f`:

```
paste -d '^' /dev/null PATTERN_FILE | grep -f - SEARCH_FILE
```

Or `sed 's/^/^/' PATTERN_FILE` instead of `paste`.

Now, if the lines in `PATTERN_FILE` are meant to be fixed strings rather than basic regular expressions, then you'd also need to escape all the regex operators:

```
sed 's/[][$^*\\.]/\\&/g; s/^/^/' PATTERN_FILE | grep -f - SEARCH_FILE
```

Comment: Additional props for mentioning the regex escape with sed. This is something I didn't consider I needed to do with my actual data, and looking at it now, I definitely need to escape errant characters that will be interpreted as regex

Answer (score 4):

Alternative: you can use awk rather than grep to do the matching:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} {for(t in a) if(substr($0,1,length(t))==t){print;next}}' needles haystack
```

This avoids the overhead of the regexp engine in grep, but has awk's interpretation overhead; I'm not sure which comes out better.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my @a = "/path/to/pattern_file.txt".IO.lines;  \
             .put if .starts-with( any @a );'  search_file.txt

#OR

~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my @a = "/path/to/pattern_file.txt".IO.lines;  \
             .put if .starts-with( [|] @a );'  search_file.txt
```

Above are answers written in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Assuming here that the `pattern_file.txt` is meant to be fixed strings rather than basic regular expressions, Raku has string-matching functions like `starts-with` and `ends-with`. Raku also has **Junctions** like `any`, `all`, `one`, and `none` that can simplify this matching problem.

Above the `-ne` non-autoprinting command line flags are used, which reads input files linewise. In a `BEGIN` block the `pattern_file.txt` is read into `@a` array. In the body of the code, the input line is out`put` if it starts with `any` element of `@a` (first answer). Alternatively (second answer), Raku's `[ ]` reduction meta-operator notation is used to conceptually insert a `|` *OR* operator between the elements of `@a`. The first and second answers give identical results.

Sample Input:

```
pattern_file.txt

    1234
    qwerty
    chicken

search_file.txt

    12345
    543212345
    qwerty
    1fwf32sgww
    chicken fingers
```

Sample Output:

```
    12345
    qwerty
    chicken fingers
```

*Note: It's tempting to think that a `one` Junction (or equivalent `[^]` reduction meta-operator) will accomplish the same task, but this only holds true if each line in `patterns_file.txt` is unique!*

https://docs.raku.org/routine/starts-with
https://docs.raku.org/type/Junction
https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Reduction_metaoperators
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

One option to do this would be to modify the patterns file first, using a command such as the following to add a `^` character to the start of each line. This would instruct grep via regex to only match at the start of the line.

```
awk '{print "^" $0}' PATTERN_FILE
```

However this modifies the pattern file, and I would prefer a solution which does not alter the original list

Comment: awk by default doesn't modify the input file; _some_ versions _optionally_ do so, like GNU awk's `-i inplace`. You could `awk '{print "^" $0}' needles | grep -f- haystack` except if needles contains regexp operators, then it's more complicated as Stéphane noted -- awk _can_ do those also, but not at easily as sed.